# How to extend a class in JavaScript, when it has no default constructor?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor

In JavaScript, how do I extend a base class, when there is no constructor suitable to use when assigning the prototype of the new class? Solution...

1. Must pass `instanceof` test.
2. Must not modify existing constructor.
3. Must call super constructor.
4. Must not include an intermediate class I write.
5. Must not have dependency on third party code, like jQuery.
6. May involve a helper function you provide.

Here is what I've tried.

```js
function Person(name) { // Immutable base class.
  if (typeof name != "string" || name == "") {
    throw new Error("A person must have a valid name.");
  }
  this.getName = function() {
    return name;
  }
}

function Artist(name) { // My extending class.
  Person.call(this, name); // Call super constructor.
}
Artist.prototype = new Person(); // Express inheritance without parameters.
var tom = new Artist("Tom");
console.info(tom instanceof Person); // Must print true.
console.info(tom.getName()); // Must print Tom.
```

My solution fails because an exception is thrown

Comment: `getName` is flawed right now

Comment: Have you considered using es6 `class` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes?

Answer (score 4):

You're doing inheritance wrong, it should be:

```js
Artist.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

That works and all your tests are passed.

Useful reading: [Inheritance in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance)